# Is it possible to run two kernels belonging to different application run concurrently?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I want to run two kernels belonging to two different CUDA programs concurrently. I don't want context switching to happen. I want both the programs to share the device. I have 14 SMs in my GPU and one program uses 2 SMs and another uses 1 SM. But I am not able to run them concurrently. The second program waits until the first one finishes its execution. The GPU device is nVidia Tesla M2050. With deviceQuery it says the card supports concurrent kernel execution (Is this for kernels belonging to one program/process/context?). Also, the device is in Default computing mode. It is not set to any exclusive mode.
Is there any way I can run them concurrently?

Comment: That can't be done with any current hardware

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896945/56875.
 GPUs can't execute in parallel kernels from two cuda contexts.

I haven't tried it before, but on linux you can try to cheat by using [CUDA-proxy](http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=alt-nvidia-current-cuda-proxy-control&section=1) which is a single process that creats single context but allows other cuda processes to use proxy's context.

Answer (score 1):

As @talonmies says in the comment - this is not currently possible. Only one CUDA context can be on the given device at any time.