# How do I use Nvidia Multi-process Service (MPS) to run multiple non-MPI CUDA applications?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, kepler

Can I run non-MPI CUDA applications concurrently on NVIDIA Kepler GPUs with MPS? I'd like to do this because my applications cannot fully utilize the GPU, so I want them to co-run together. Is there any code example to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The necessary instructions are contained in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) for the MPS service.  You'll note that those instructions don't really depend on or call out MPI, so there really isn't anything MPI-specific about them.

Here's a walkthrough/example.

1. Read section 2.3 of the above-linked documentation for various requirements and restrictions.  I recommend using CUDA 7, 7.5, or later for this.   There were some configuration differences with prior versions of CUDA MPS that I won't cover here.  Also, I'll demonstrate just using a single server/single GPU.  The machine I am using for test is a CentOS 6.2 node using a K40c (cc3.5/Kepler) GPU, with CUDA 7.0.  There are other GPUs in the node.  In my case, the CUDA enumeration order places my K40c at device 0, but the nvidia-smi enumeration order happens to place it as id 2 in the order.  All of these details matter in a system with multiple GPUs, impacting the scripts given below.
2. I'll create several helper bash scripts and also a test application.  For the test application, we'd like something with kernel(s) that can obviously run concurrently with kernels from other instances of the application, and we'd also like something that makes it obvious when those kernels (from separate apps/processes) are running concurrently or not.  To meet these needs for demonstration purposes, let's have an app that has a kernel that just runs in a single thread on a single SM, and simply waits for a period of time (we'll use ~5 seconds) before exiting and printing a message.  Here's a test app that does that:

   ```
   $ cat t1034.cu
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   #define MAX_DELAY 30

   #define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
     do { \
       cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
       if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
           fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
               msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
               __FILE__, __LINE__); \
           fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
           exit(1); \
       } \
     } while (0)


   #include <time.h>
   #include <sys/time.h>
   #define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

   unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

     timeval tv;
     gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
     return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
   }

   #define APPRX_CLKS_PER_SEC 1000000000ULL
   __global__ void delay_kernel(unsigned seconds){

     unsigned long long dt = clock64();
     while (clock64() < (dt + (seconds*APPRX_CLKS_PER_SEC)));
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     unsigned delay_t = 5; // seconds, approximately
     unsigned delay_t_r;
     if (argc > 1) delay_t_r = atoi(argv[1]);
     if ((delay_t_r > 0) && (delay_t_r < MAX_DELAY)) delay_t = delay_t_r;
     unsigned long long difft = dtime_usec(0);
     delay_kernel<<<1,1>>>(delay_t);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
     difft = dtime_usec(difft);
     printf("kernel duration: %fs\n", difft/(float)USECPSEC);
     return 0;
   }


   $ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1034 t1034.cu
   $ ./t1034
   kernel duration: 6.528574s
   $
   ```
3. We'll use a bash script to start the MPS server:

   ```
   $ cat start_as_root.bash
   #!/bin/bash
   # the following must be performed with root privilege
   export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"
   nvidia-smi -i 2 -c EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS
   nvidia-cuda-mps-control -d
   $
   ```
4. And a bash script to launch 2 copies of our test app "simultaneously":

   ```
   $ cat mps_run
   #!/bin/bash
   ./t1034 &
   ./t1034
   $
   ```
5. We could also have a bash script to shut down the server, although it's not needed for this walkthrough:

   ```
   $ cat stop_as_root.bash
   #!/bin/bash
   echo quit | nvidia-cuda-mps-control
   nvidia-smi -i 2 -c DEFAULT
   $
   ```
6. Now when we just launch our test app using the `mps_run` script above, but without actually enabling the MPS server, we get the expected behavior that one instance of the app takes the expected ~5 seconds, whereas the other instance takes approximately double that (~10 seconds) because, since it does not run concurrently with an app from another process, it waits for 5 seconds while the other app/kernel is running, and then spends 5 seconds running its own kernel, for a total of ~10 seconds:

   ```
   $ ./mps_run
   kernel duration: 6.409399s
   kernel duration: 12.078304s
   $
   ```
7. On the other hand, if we start the MPS server first, and repeat the test:

   ```
   $ su
   Password:
   # ./start_as_root.bash
   Set compute mode to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS for GPU 0000:82:00.0.
   All done.
   # exit
   exit
   $ ./mps_run
   kernel duration: 6.167079s
   kernel duration: 6.263062s
   $
   ```

   we see that both apps take the same amount of time to run, because the kernels are running concurrently, due to MPS.
8. You're welcome to experiment as you see fit.  If this sequence appears to work correctly for you, but running your own application doesn't seem to give the expected results, one possible reason may be that your app/kernels are not able to run concurrently with other instances of the app/kernels due to the construction of your kernels, not anything to do with MPS.  You might want to verify [the requirements for concurrent kernels](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution), and/or study the [concurrentKernels sample app](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels).
9. Much of the information here was recycled from the test/work done [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/887822/fail-to-launch-cuda-mps/) albeit the presentation here with separate apps is different than the MPI case presented there.

**UPDATE**: The scheduler behavior in the non-MPS case when running kernels from multiple processes appears to have changed with Pascal and newer GPUs.  The above test results still are correct for the GPUs tested on (e.g. Kepler), but when running the above test case on a Pascal or newer GPU, different results will be observed in the non-MPS case.  The scheduler is described as a "time-sliced" scheduler in [the latest MPS doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) and what appears to be happening is that rather than wait for a kernel from one process to complete, the scheduler may, according to some unpublished rules, choose to pre-empt a running kernel so that it can switch to another kernel from another process.  This still doesn't mean that kernels from separate processes are running "concurrently" in the traditional usage of that word in CUDA documentation, but the above code is "tricked" by the time-sliced scheduler (on Pascal and newer) because it depends on using the SM clock to set kernel duration.  The combination of the time-sliced scheduler plus this usage of the SM clock makes this test case appear to run "concurrently".  However, as described in the MPS doc, the code from kernel A is not executing in the same clock cycle(s) as the code from kernel B, when A and B originate from separate processes in the non-MPS case.

An alternative method to demonstrate this using the above general approach might be to use a kernel duration that is set by a number of loops, rather than a kernel duration that is set by reading the SM clock, as described [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032865/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-kernels-from-different-process-can-run-concurrently-same-performance-with-mps-on-and-off-/?offset=9#5255696).  Care must be taken in that case to avoid having the loops "optimized out" by the compiler.

Comment: Is it possible to implement MPS by CUDA from scratch?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Can you please share your thoughts regarding this question? Why do you think it's impossible? Does it seem that MPS uses some undocumented driver API or something like that?

Comment: MPS takes work (e.g. CUDA kernel launches) that is issued from separate processes, and runs them on the device as if they emanated from a single process.  As if they are running in a single context.  I don't know how to do that with the currently exposed APIs that I'm familiar with.  Beyond that I don't have any further thoughts and will be **unlikely to respond to further questions on that topic**.