# Can GPU supports multiple jobs without delay?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch, nvidia

So I am running PyTorch deep learning job using GPU
but the job is pretty light.

My GPU has 8 GB but the job only uses 2 GB. Also GPU-Util is close to 0%.

```
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   36C    P2    45W / 210W |   1155MiB /  8116MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

based on GPU-Util and memory I might be able to fit in another 3 jobs.

However, I am not sure if that will affect the overall runtime.

If I run multiple jobs on same GPU does that affects the overall runtime?

I think tried once and I think there was delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. One option is to use NVIDIA's Multi-Process Service (MPS) to run four copies of your model on the same card.

This is the best description I have found of how to do it: [How do I use Nvidia Multi-process Service (MPS) to run multiple non-MPI CUDA applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709749/how-do-i-use-nvidia-multi-process-service-mps-to-run-multiple-non-mpi-cuda-app)

If you are using your card for inference only, then you can host several models (either copies, or different models) on the same card using NVIDIA's [TensorRT Inference Service](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-inference-server-guide/docs/).

Comment: I am pretty upset that I have to do something explicit to get it working but I guess, it is only option. Thanks