Creating a CUDA context for each CPU thread takes too much GPU memory
I am working on an application that makes use of NVIDIA decoding capabilities. In this app I handle the decoding of several video streams (18 in total), each one on a different CPU thread, so I create a new CUDA context with cuCtxCreate() for each of them.
I am trying to run this app on a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 and creating this many contexts is a problem since each one of them takes a lot of GPU memory (~400MB each). I used to work on a NVIDIA Quadro P4000 and the memory required by each context was much lower.
Is there any way of reducing the amount of GPU memory taken by each context created?
Thank you very much!

To check that the problem does not come from any other process in my app, I wrote this simple code which creates a set of threads and each one of them creates a CUDA context. The result here is the same, each new thread takes around 400 MB of GPU memory on my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

static size_t previous_ocupancy = 0;

void threadFunction(int threadID) {

    size_t free_mem, total_mem = 0;

    int GPU_device = 0;
    CUdevice device;
    CUresult res = cuDeviceGet(&device, GPU_device);
    if (res != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get device: " << GPU_device << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
    std::cout << ">>>cuDeviceGet: GPU FREE MEMORY: " << free_mem/1000000000.0 << ", Reserved: " << (total_mem-free_mem)/1000000000.0 << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(threadID));


    if (previous_ocupancy == 0) {
        previous_ocupancy = free_mem;
    }

    // Create CUDA context
    CUcontext g_oContext;
    res = cuCtxCreate(&g_oContext, CU_CTX_SCHED_BLOCKING_SYNC, device);
    if (res != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create context." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
    std::cout << ">>>cuCtxDestroy: GPU FREE MEMORY: " << free_mem/1000000000.0
              << ", Reserved: " << (total_mem-free_mem)/1000000000.0
              << ", CTX memory: " << (previous_ocupancy-free_mem)/1000000.0 << " MiB" << std::endl;

    previous_ocupancy = free_mem;

    std::cout << "Thread " << threadID << " finished.\n";


    // Wait and start destroying CTX
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(40 + threadID));


    res = cuCtxDestroy(g_oContext);
    if (res != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create context." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
    std::cout << ">>>cuCtxDestroy: GPU FREE MEMORY: " << free_mem/1000000000.0
              << ", Reserved: " << (total_mem-free_mem)/1000000000.0 << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    int numThreads = 18; 

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    cuInit(0);

    // Create and start threads
    std::cout << "All threads START.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(threadFunction, i));
    }

    // Wait for all threads to complete
    for (auto &th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }

    std::cout << "All threads have finished.\n";
    return 0;
}


use a single context across all threads.   Don't create a new context in each thread, instead create one context and pass it into each thread for use. Or switch to the runtime API.

As nVidia documentation and 2018 forum discussion say, the context memory overhead is dependent on the number of streaming multiprocessors (SMs) implemented on your CUDA device core, and there is sadly no known method to determine this behaviour. But it is only part of the answer. The actual overhead may dramatically depend on the host OS, as it was reported before for Windows in this answer. The answer is quite new (2021), so the issue may be still present in your setup. But as I see here, likely you have the strange threading model issue also described (but sadly not solved!) here.
As it is described here, the solution may be to run everything in the single host process. If it is not an option, it seems the best way to look at nVidia MPS, and here is an excellent answer about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34711344/9560245
