# Does it make sense to multithread two different neural networks on one GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have two neural networks represented as Python classes A and B. Methods `A.run()` and `B.run()` represent a feedforward inference for one image.

As an example, `A.run()` takes 100 ms, and `B.run()` takes 50 ms.

When ran one after another, i.e.

```
img = cap.read()[1]  # e.g. cv2.VideoCapture instance
start_time = time.time()
A.run(img)  # 100 ms
B.run(img)  # 50 ms
time_diff = time.time() - start_time  # 100 + 50 = 150 ms
```

the inference times just add up to 150 ms.

To make this faster, we can try parallelizing so that they start at the same time. An implementation that uses Python's threading is outlined below:

```
class A:
    # This method is spawned using Python's threading library
    def run_queue(self, input_queue, output_queue):
        while True:
            img = input_queue.get()
            start_time = time.time()
            output = self.run(img)  
            time_diff = time.time() - start_time # Supposedly 100 ms for class A, and 50 ms for class B


# in main program flow:            
# Assume that a_input_queue and a_output_queue are tied to an instance of class A
# And similar for class B

img = cap.read()[1]
a_input_queue.put(img)
b_input_queue.put(img)

start_time = time.time()
a_output = a_output_queue.get()  # Should take 100 ms
b_output = b_output_queue.get()  # B.run() should take 50 ms, but since it started at the same time as A.run(), this get() should effectively return immediately
time_diff = time.time() - start_time  # Should theoretically be 100 ms
```

So theoretically, we should only be bottlenecked by A, and end up with 100 ms for the whole system.

However, it seems that B.run() takes around 100 ms as well when measured in `B.run_queue()`. Since they started at around the same time, the whole system also takes around a 100 ms.

Does this make sense? Is trying to thread the two neural networks sensible, if the resulting total inference time is about the same (or possibly incrementally faster at least)?

My guess is that the GPU is maxed at 100% for one neural network, so when trying to inference two networks at the same time, it just rearranges the instructions but can only do the same number of computations anyway:

```
Illustration:
A.run() executes 8 blocks of instructions:
| X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
B.run() executes only 4 blocks of instructions:
| Y | Y | Y | Y |

Now, say that the GPU can process 2 blocks of instructions per second.

So, in the case that A.run() and B.run() are ran one after the other (non-threaded):
| X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | Y | Y | Y | Y | -> A.run() takes 4 s, B.run() takes 2 s, everything takes 6 s

In the threaded case, the instructions are rearranged so both start at the same time, but get stretched out:
| X | X | Y | X | X | Y | X | X | Y | X | X | Y  -> A.run() roughly takes 6 s, B.run() roughly takes 6 s, everything seems to take 6 s
```

Is the above illustration the case?

Finally, let's consider a class C similar to B (e.g. inference time=50 ms), except that it uses the CPU. Thus, it shouldn't compete with A in GPU usage, but from experiments, it just behaved like B; its inference time seemed to be stretched to match A's.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several things to consider here. First, CUDA tasks are generally serialized in the GPU (see [Running more than one CUDA applications on one GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31643570)). Then there is the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gil/info), which I'm not sure when, if at all, is freed when TensorFlow runs a graph (in GPU or CPU). You would probably have more success "merging" the two models in one graph to compute the outputs at the same time. However, multithreading can be useful with GPU for [pipelining](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#pipelining).

Comment: Thanks. Changed the code to use multiprocessing.Process instead of threading.Thread to get around the GIL, but as you have pointed out, CUDA would serialize them anyway.