# Run a Python function on a GPU using Ray

Tags: python, gpu, ray

I'm using a Python package called [Ray](https://www.ray.io) to run the example shown below in parallel. The code is run on a machine with 80 CPU cores and 4 GPUs.

```py
import ray
import time

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def squared(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    y = x**2
    return y

tic = time.perf_counter()

lazy_values = [squared.remote(x) for x in range(1000)]
values = ray.get(lazy_values)

toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Elapsed time {toc - tic:.2f} s')
print(f'{values[:5]} ... {values[-5:]}')

ray.shutdown()
```

Output from the above example is:

```
Elapsed time 13.09 s
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16] ... [990025, 992016, 994009, 996004, 998001]
```

Below is the same example, but I would like to run it on the GPU using the `num_gpus` parameter. The GPUs available on the machine are Nvidia Tesla V100.

```py
import ray
import time

ray.init(num_gpus=1)

@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
def squared(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    y = x**2
    return y

tic = time.perf_counter()

lazy_values = [squared.remote(x) for x in range(1000)]
values = ray.get(lazy_values)

toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Elapsed time {toc - tic:.2f} s')
print(f'{values[:5]} ... {values[-5:]}')

ray.shutdown()
```

The GPU example never completed and I terminated it after several minutes. I checked the resources available to Ray using `import ray; ray.init(); ray.available_resources()` and it reports 80 CPUs and 4 GPUs. So it seems that Ray knows about the available GPUs.

I modified the GPU example to run fewer executions by changing `range(1000)` to `range(10)`. See the revised example below.

```py
import ray
import time

ray.init(num_gpus=1)

@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
def squared(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    y = x**2
    return y

tic = time.perf_counter()

lazy_values = [squared.remote(x) for x in range(10)]
values = ray.get(lazy_values)

toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Elapsed time {toc - tic:.2f} s')
print(f'{values[:5]} ... {values[-5:]}')

ray.shutdown()
```

The output from the revised GPU example is:

```
Elapsed time 10.06 s
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16] ... [25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

The revised GPU example completed, but it looks like Ray is not using the GPU in parallel. Is there something else I should do to get Ray to run on the GPU in parallel?

Comment: You can probably try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77025640/5762249
However, you should keep in mind that using Ray for trivial workloads might even damage the performance, as stated in the "Avoid tiny tasks" section here:  https://rise.cs.berkeley.edu/blog/ray-tips-for-first-time-users/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
```

That tells ray that your function will consume the entire GPU.  Thus, it runs serially.  The documentation says you should specify a fractional number here to get multiprocessing:

```
@ray.remote(num_gpus = 0.1)
```

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-gpus.html

Comment: Ah, I see. So in the example where I have 1,000 tasks defined as `range(1000)`, what would be an appropriate value for `num_gpus` using an Nvidia Tesla V100? The specs for the GPU are 640 tensor cores and 5,120 CUDA cores.

Comment: Would 1 / N be a good place to start for a `num_gpus` value? Where N would be the number of tasks that are run. For example if N = 1000 then 1 / N = 0.001 therefore `num_gpus=0.001`.

Comment: I think this is a matter for experimentation.  You just want to avoid oversubscribing the memory.  And if you have 4 GPUs, why not tell that to `ray.init`?

Comment: I just want to use one of the GPUs to conserve resources which is why I used `ray.init(num_gpus=1)`. But yeah, I could tell Ray to use all the GPUs too. I just didn't understand how to properly utilize the function on the GPU. So thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sounds like you want use placement_groups. They will reserve a certain amount of resources that your task cannot exceed.